# Pagination inside a button process in php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Please help me to find a solution
My page is to search for the logs present between two days and I have got 30 results showing in one page- now i want to do the pagination in it showing 10 at a time. The thing is after only clicking the search will show. How can I direct to page1, page 2 and page 3 in this case. 
If anybody knows then I can inbox my code!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['searchlog']))
{
  if($status=="OK")
  {
    echo '<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID Tarif</th>
      <th>Date/Time</th>
      <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    $page=$_GET["page"];
    if($page==""||$page=="1")
    { 
      $page1=0;
    }
    else
    {
      $page1=($page*10)-10;
    }
    $s="SELECT * FROM logs WHERE dt BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' ORDER BY dt DESC  LIMIT('$page1',10) ";
    $x=mysql_query($s);
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($x))
    {
     echo "<tr><td>".$r['id_tarif']."</td><td>".$r['dt']."</td><td>".$r['note']."</td></tr>";
    }
    $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE dt BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' ORDER BY dt DESC ");
    $x=  mysql_num_rows($s);
    $count=  ceil($x/10);
    for($j=1;$j<=$count;$j++)
    {
      echo '<a href="viewlog.php?page='.$j.'">'.$j.'            </a>';
    }
  }
}
closedb();
?>
```